# Camel route processing IBM MQ messages with a big delay

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

We have a testing tool stabbing external systems our micro-services interact with via different endpoints. One of this stabs is a listener to an IBM MQ queue build as an Apache Camel route. Once receiving a message the stub builds three associate responses and sends them back to a response queue. This is very little processing usually taking anywhere between 10 to 20 milliseconds to complete.

Part of our performance testing, messages are injected into our application and in turn the application will interact with the stab. At around 60 messages per second I cannot say the load is big. From application logs the processing is quite fast; however we noticed performance degradation because there is a big waiting time when messages stay in the request queue waiting to be picked up by the stub.

We have six instances of the testing tool running as ECS tasks and each one was running the given stub with one consumer. We increased the number of concurrent consumers to 3 than to 10 then to 20 but it did not make a lot of difference. Wondering where the problem is.

The message consumption is transactional (no XA) and we wrap `MQQueueConnectionFactory` with Spring's `CachingConnectionFactory` with a session cache size of 500

**UPDATE:**

The Apache Camel route definition starts like below:

```
from("jms:my.request.queue?concurrentConsumers=20&disableReplyTo=true")
    .routeId("my-stub")
    .autoStartup(true)
    .policy(somePlatformTransactionPolicy)
    .process(...)
    // a bunch of processors doing their in memory stuff
    .to("jms.my.response.queue")
```

Note that behind the scenes Apache Camel JMS component uses a Spring `JmsTemplate` for sending messages and Spring `MessageListenerContainer` for consuming.

[camel jms-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/jms-component.html)

I did not look into which `MessageListenerContainer` implementation Apache Camel uses but I am quite confident they will be using [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) which is the most used JMS listener in the Spring world. This default listener extends `AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer` so it works by polling.

I had a look at the JmsComponent implementation and I can confirm it is using an extension of Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`

```
/**
 * The default {@link DefaultMessageListenerContainer container} which listen for messages on the JMS destination.
 * <p/>
 * This implementation extends Springs {@link 
DefaultMessageListenerContainer} supporting automatic recovery and
 * throttling.
 */
public class DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {
```

Comment: How is the stub kicked off to pick up messages from the request queue? Is it polling? Is it triggered?

Comment: Added more details in the question

Comment: Is it only listening on one queue - the queue showing the problem, or does it have multiple queues it is listening on? Is it already listening on the queue before you put the messages or is there a start up process that must be considered too?

Comment: The stab application is already started when the testing framework start throwing messages into the flow. Also for a very short run (seconds) the messages are processed immediately. If you follow the link I provided for `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` you will see Spring recommendation "Note: Don't use Spring's CachingConnectionFactory in combination with dynamic scaling. Ideally, don't use it with a message listener container at all". I found out we were using that. Changed the code but not tested yet. Fingers crossed.

Comment: It is only one queue that the listener points to.

Comment: Fingers Crossed

Comment: Injecting a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` that no longer uses a `CachingConnectionFactory` into the Camel route made a `huge difference`. The messages were processed off the queue in no time and we could see the number of concurrent consumers scaling up and down as the load increased/decreased.